# AngularJS $apply not called in an interval when the $scope has changed from one controller to another and back

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating this directive with Angular that works as a mini timer. I don't need anything more than just counting seconds and minutes. The directive works great as long as I stay on the page where the directive is called.

The issue is when I switch to another page then come back, I need the timer to still be displayed with the current time.

I have a global `window.timer` object which keeps the state of the timer.

```
app.directive('callTimer', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: function($scope, $rootScope) {
      $scope.minutes = (window.timer.state.minutes || 0)
      $scope.seconds = (window.timer.state.seconds || 0)

      $scope.startTimer = function() {
        window.timer.interval = window.setInterval(function() {
          // incrementTimer
          window.timer.state = {minutes: $scope.minutes,seconds: $scope.seconds};
          $scope.$apply($scope.updateDisplay);
        }, 1000);
      };

      $scope.stopTimer = function() { /*stuff to stop timer*/};

      $scope.updateDisplay = function() {
        $scope.minDisplay = String($scope.minutes).padLeft('0', 2);
        $scope.secDisplay = String($scope.seconds).padLeft('0', 2);
      };

      $scope.updateDisplay();
    }
  };
});
```

Here is the html

```
<call-timer>{{minDisplay}}:{{secDisplay}}</call-timer>
```

The timer is on my home page. When I go to another page, the timer will continue to count, but when I come back to the home page, my `updateDisplay` function isn't called.

**EDIT:** adding in more of the directive code.

Comment: Why not use Angular's `$interval` or `$timeout`, which can be injected into your directive/controller/whatever

Comment: I originally used that, but the interval was destroyed everytime I changed controllers. I may have missed something though. I'm pretty new to angular.

Comment: You mention that this is in a directive, can you post the directive code? (depending on where in the directive your code is could lie the problem)

Comment: I imagine that `$scope.startTimer()` is called each time this directive is run?

Comment: yeah. I figured it out. I posted my code for what I'm doing. Probably a better way, but this works for now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

|Is it a single page app ? If yes do not store the timer within directive. Store it in some controller or another place.Directives get recreated when you navigate to another page so there is no possible way of storing timer value within directive.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured this out. The issue is that the $scope inside of the interval is actually a different instance of the controller than what's outside after you've gone from one controller to another and back. Here is my code (It's actually in coffeescript).

It's not the prettiest, but the idea is to pass which scope I want to use when I update the view. If anyone has an idea of how I can clean this up, that would be awesome, but this code does exactly what I needed.

https://gist.github.com/jwoertink/5256e80f393a150f8b21